My supervisor wants me to switch to another software/programming language that I am not proficient in. What to do?
How can I address my professor’s insistence on switching to SAS when I’m already proficient in R and Python?
I’m facing a dilemma where my professor keeps urging me to switch to SAS for my work, despite my extensive experience with R and intermediate skills in Python. I find SAS to be outdated compared to the flexibility and power of R and Python, and honestly, I really dislike using it. I’ve tried to learn it, but I just can’t find the motivation. It is also disappointing to do things in both R and SAS and sometimes seeing different results. How can I approach this situation without damaging my relationship with my professor or compromising the quality of my work? This is somehow also affecting my health and my motivation for the job.

Why do they want you to switch? "I see you are not making any progress, switch to my pet tool" and "everyone else in the lab uses it, we need your work to be compatible" are different situations.

"It is also disappointing to do things in both R and SAS and sometimes seeing different results" (assuming SAS is indeed the stats software) is kind of a red flag, results should not vary. Results should be independent of the tool/language.
From another perspective, imagine you are the Prof and faced with the following situation: 1) The student (assuming here) uses R/Python and you cannot follow the results. 2) The student uses SAS and you understand the results.
The prof's conclusion in such a situation might be (unfortunately) simple: Student doing #2 works, #1 does not, so do #2.

Frankly, learning yet-another-software-package should not be a particularly large burden, and you get to put experience with that package on your resume which should be a bonus. If you are getting different answers from different packages, that is a whole other problem.

How different are these different results? Is the error like 10^-12 or 10^-2 ?

You will continue to be asked to learn new programming languages and skills for the rest of your career, and you will get used to it.

While I can easily believe that having to learn outdated software would affect your motivation, I seriously doubt that it affects your health. Probably best to avoid claiming that it does.

Are you seriously fighting your professor over him/her making you learn something?

@TerryLoring Maybe p = 0.0499999 and p = 0.0500001.

If you are doing a fairly standard type of analysis, the different results are probably not due to an error in either package, but slightly different methods/calculations. There can be more than one way to calculate regression parameters, standard errors, confidence intervals, etc. Read the documentation in detail, and in R you might need to look at the source code, which can be hard to understand.

@cag51 Mental health is health

True, but claiming "this is bad for my (mental) health!" every time you have to do something you don't want to do is not a good strategy. Not saying that's necessarily what this OP is doing, but what OP wrote could certainly be interpreted that way.

My understanding is some research fields (medical research I believe) considered SAS as the "gold standard" and the core libraries are mature, heavily curated and validated for correctness. If you're in one of these fields expect resistance to R and Python as many will consider the libraries far less well tested - since open source libraries are more likely to "move fast and break stuff"

What is your role?

First step is to ask why the request to change. You've summarized the rationale for your preference, but you haven't indicated what your professor's rationale is. If you're working collaboratively with others, there may be a strong reason to change to match them. Or there may be a corpus of tools in one language in your field. Both of those are strong reasons.
Or your professor may be worried they may not be able to follow and evaluate what you do, or be misinformed about what the capabilities of different languages/environments are. Those are less valid reasons, in that they can be addressed in dialogue, but you need to engage with them.
Finally, there is an important difference based on your role (and funding). If you are working independently on your own research topic, and your professor is an advisor and evaluator only, then ultimately you choose to take or reject their advice. And deal with the consequences, if your choice is suboptimal (for any number of reasons). Versus if you are part of -- and funded by -- your professor's research lab and research grants, in which case you can bring your arguments to the table (and understand and engage with your professor's arguments), but ultimately you will need to adapt to whatever your supervisor, in this case your boss, decides.


It is also disappointing to do things in both R and SAS and sometimes seeing different results.

This is great! It means that you found a bug in your code that would have otherwise gone unnoticed.
If you look around this site, you'll find a lot of "I found a fundamental error in my thesis after submitting it and it freaks me out" kind of questions. Congratulations, you just prevented that from happening.
Use your R skills to your advantage: Learn SAS and do your analysis with it. If anything looks fishy, validate your results with R. Since you have a lot of experience with R, this should be easily doable. If the results differ, find out why and experience the joy of research: Finding out why things are the way they are.
If, on the other hand, learning new tools and digging deep into unsolved problems gives you anxiety rather than joy, that is also an important result: It means that staying in (this branch of) academia might not be the right choice for you, and it's another data point that you can use to decide upon your future career.

Not wanting to dig deep into implementation details of R vs SAS is not a sign of a bad academic. For many academics the software they use is just a tool.

And wanting to understand your tools is a sign of a good academic.

I do agree that getting more perspective from your advisor about why they want you to use SAS is a good idea. For example, it could be that it's something they're more familiar with, and so can directly comment and assist you with your analyses, in a way that would be difficult if they're in a language that they don't understand. Although it may be tedious for you to pick up a new language, there's real value in being able to get direct, specific feedback from your advisor on your analysis!
Something else to  consider is that SAS is still the language of choice for many biostatistics jobs, especially in fields related to clinical science and public health. Although analysis can of course be done in any language, I think the reason SAS remains prevalent in those fields is for regulatory reasons (i.e. they have specific processes in place that were certified in some way, and they use SAS code and so must be maintained using SAS code). If those types of jobs are at all interesting to you, spending some time picking up SAS as a graduate student could be beneficial. Every time I'm on the job market I think "damn, I should have learned SAS" because there are inevitably a bunch of jobs that require years of SAS experience.
Finally, regarding your point about differences in results between SAS and R: make sure to pay attention to the type of sums of squares you're comparing between SAS and R. This may be outdated, but it was a huge issue when I was in grad school in biology in 2010 and the field was transitioning from SAS to R. My memory was that the ANOVA function in SAS provides Type-III sums of squares results by default, whereas the ANOVA function in R provides Type-I sums of squares. So, depending on whether you have interaction terms in your models you will likely see differences in the results unless you specify the same sums of squares. Apologies if this isn't the issue that you're seeing, but this was such a vexing issue for my cohort so I thought I'd mention just in case it was useful.

As most answers have stated, you certainly must have an honest, frank, and open discussion with your advisor to determine why you are being asked (if not required) to use one computational tool when you prefer to use another. The opposing side for your discussion is also important to prepare. You have yet to demonstrate objectively why your preferred choice in a computer tool must be (rather than should be) used. Statements such as "it is outdated" infer subjective "I feel this way (about the user interface)" sentiments. Can you prove that one package uses outdated computational methods versus the other? The note that your results from the two different packages do not agree with each other can mean that you, as the user, are doing two different methods using each one. Can you reconcile your inconsistencies and still find that one tool gives a presumably correct answer while the other gives a presumably incorrect answer for exactly the same computational processing?
Of course, you are not called in this forum to present any of the above supportive discussion, not even in outline form. Debates on the objective reasons why one software platform or application is "better" than another software platform or application can and do fill general forums on computer software as well as support forums for the specific tools themselves. Such discussions belong there, absolutely not here.
So, before you visit your advisor to ask why, you should prepare an objectively researched marketing package to support your case.

Visit the support forums for your two opposing packages. Find what each forum says in comparison to the other. I suspect (without proof, but with confidence) that some hints will be given about the pros and cons of one package versus the other. What do you discover that supports your case? What do you discover that supports your advisor's case? If cost is no limit, is one package generally stated to be preferred over another for the work that you must do?

Document objectively the cases where your time to complete task X in software package A (your preferred) is consistently and significantly shorter than your time to complete task X in software package B (your advisor's preferred). Clear for yourself and for your advisor how that difference is a function of how the two packages allow the work to be done rather than as a function of your clumsiness or lack of experience in using package B versus package A.

My favorite (as one who demands publication-ready quality in outputs from science/engineering software) ... Demonstrate outputs from package A and package B where the results agree yet the quality in the output from A (your choice) is noticeably higher than from B for the same nominal effort in input time/effort invested. Yes, quality metrics can vary from person to person and from discipline to discipline. Yet I would argue that any step in quality that accentuates content over glitter and as well does not loose key meta-information with such things as fonts being too small or esoteric labeling will always stand out no matter who is the final judge.



The opinion that one programming language is just "better" than another is in most cases wrong (excepting maybe esoteric languages). However, it is likely that as a SAS beginner, you are unaware of concise, efficient and readable ways to do the things you need to get done in SAS. Maybe there are SAS idioms or functions that could elegantly solve your specific problems, but there is a bit of a learning curve to finding them. I think this is one of the main reasons why using a new programming language can seem uncomfortable at first.
I think maybe large language models could help speed up the process by teaching you the constructions that are relevant to your use cases.
If you have some code in R/Python that is reasonably small and modular, and if confidentiality considerations don't stand in the way, you could try to see if a large language model can translate it well to SAS. Some of these models are fairly good at small-ish programming tasks (at the time of writing, I'd say Claude-3.5-Sonnet is the best one at that kind of thing), and I would expect that good translations of your code will turn out to be more elegant and idiomatic than what you might produce as a beginner in a new language. If so, having such translations of code that you (hopefully) already thoroughly understand can help you learn that language and do some part of the work of migrating your codebase, to the extent that you are required to.
My guess is that after seeing and understanding that code, the likelihood is high that you will come to the conclusion that either tool has some advantages and disadvantages over the other, and that you can live with migrating.
That said, I agree fully with the previous posters that you should seek to understand why your professor is trying to make you migrate. If you are getting non-equivalent results for the same data with functions that you believe should be equivalent in R/Python and SAS, understanding the reasons for that should also be a high priority.

Using LLMs to translate a code to another language doesn't solve the problem. You still have to know the fundamentals (syntax and semantics) of the target language.

Yes. But neither is it clear that OP doesn't know the fundamentals of SAS (it seems to me he probably does), nor does getting stuff translated automatically mean one cannot then learn from the translation.

This is a good answer, but we academics are so grumpy about LLMs that we do not recognize their legitimate uses, evidently.


The opinion that one programming language is just "better" than another is in most cases wrong ... < Opinions go both ways. Your opinion about opinions can equally be deconstructed as imbalanced because it lacks objective metrics. Granted, the OP may also be mistaking subjective sentiments as being valid, objective reasons to force a decision to go a preferred way. This mistake is however not the sentiment to address as you have done. Essentially, everything but your last paragraph could be taken as an admonishment (polite as it may be framed) to suck it up and learn the other language too.


This isn't really just an everyday question about language choice & simple syntax translation. In the statistical realm, the choice of language itself is nowhere near as important as the availability of a wider ecosystem of third-party extension packages. In the statistical domain, the vast majority of current research and development occurs in open source communities, around open languages like R and Python. 20 years ago, a proprietary environment like SAS likely had the advantage in terms of power, polish, and quality assurance and certification, but the ground has really shifted since then.

Disclaimer: The following can vary by country and by law! Consider with caution:
There is a fundamental difference in:

Professor is your boss, you are his employee and get a salary:
Your boss has the right of deciding how things are to be done. He has managerial/decisional prerogative. I would assume that this is the case in every country (but I don't know in your case for certain).
However, you have signed a contract and in this contract has to be defined what your tasks and obligations are. If you are employed as an R developer, he cannot urge/command you to use SAS now without negotiating a new contract with you or at least try to support you in learning it (giving you time, resources, paying for a course or whatever).

Professor is your supervisor, you are a student writing a thesis or paper:
Your professor most likely has in mind that for the specific research topic "using X because I am good with it" is not appropriate in the context of the research field or topic. This is heavily dependent on the focus of the thesis. In some cases which approach you take does not matter. In other cases it does matter a lot.


Recommendation
Ask him, if the urge to switch is because of

an authority decision where you have no choice
is it considered a recommendation, where you can chose
is it considered important because, you have to proof or give reason why your way is the best/better instead of SAS (within the thesis/paper)
is it considered necessary for the research topic
what are the consequences if you would or would not switch.

If you can talk freely/openly mention your concerns about health and enthusiasm.
Keep in mind: Nobody can force you (this is not slavery). Quitting is your ultimate right to handle the situation. Keep this joker to you for the next conversation though and hope you see clearer after asking your prof.
Even if you are angry, don't say something like "Then I will quit!" just give your thanks and end the conversation. Then go home (not at once, after you finished your hours!), cool off and sleep a night over it. Think carefully about the pros&cons and also get advise from someone you trust (family usually, there are university counselors also you can visit). Only consider quitting if it is okay for your financial situation. But maybe keep looking for a different job to have options in the near future.
Going to work but feeling not happy there is a sure way to burn out. Don't stay in such a situation forever!

Often a professor is simultaneously a boss and supervisor for a graduate student when the student is paid from the professor's grants.

@BryanKrause: I thought about that as well... the paying aspect would make it more of the case of having a contract. The recommendation would stand anyway, would you agree?

+1. Many scholars are simply unaware that in many countries a supervisor is not the boss of the student, and that the student can literally finish the PhD without the supervisor's consent!
